# Using the scrollwheel in GNU screen -- Trusty specific difference

Tags: mouse-scroll, gnu-screen

I'd like to setup GNU screen to allow the mouse's scrollwheel to scroll around in the scrollback buffer, same question as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359109/using-the-scrollwheel-in-gnu-screen

The solution from that question--making an entry in .screenrc--which also appears many other times this question is asked, works fine for me on Precise, but applying the same fix in Trusty and then using the scroll wheel just results in scrolling the command history. I also tried the suggestion from the comments of the linked question of disabling the option "Use keystrokes to scroll on alternate screen" but that didn't help either.