# Scrollwheel in GNU screen in xfce4-terminal

Tags: 14.04, mouse-scroll, xterm, gnu-screen, xfce4-terminal

I apologize that this is pretty much a duplicate of [Using the scrollwheel in GNU screen -- Trusty specific difference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501664/using-the-scrollwheel-in-gnu-screen-trusty-specific-difference) but I don't have enough reputation to comment on that and I can provide much more information about the issue that might help with answering both of us.

I am currently running Xubuntu 14.04 Trusty as a clean install and having an issue with the scrollwheel functionality when running GNU `screen` in an `xfce4-terminal`.  This issue did not occur in Xubuntu 12.04.  In fact, since I spend a lot of time in a terminal window using screen this functionality was appreciated.

Here's how to replicate it:

Open `xfce4-terminal`.
Start `screen`.
Run `ls /usr/bin` (or anything to get more than the terminal height in lines).
Attempt to scroll up with the scrollwheel with the cursor in the output window.

What happens:  Previous entries from `.bash_history` show on the command line

Expected behavior:  Scroll back through the output

Also note, that at least in my case, the scrollbar seems to 'jump up' about 20 lines even though the output is not scrolled.  If I click on the scrollbar the output 'jumps up' to that position.  Dragging the scrollbar down puts the output where it belongs.  Also note that if I hover over the scrollbar and use the scrollwheel it functions as intended.

I have Google'd all manner of permutations of my issue and have made a modifications to my .screenrc which, ironically, fixed the problem when connecting to the machine via `PuTTY`:

```
term xterm-256color
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@  <= this is what fixed it in PuTTY
caption always
defscrollback 4000
startup_message off
msgminwait 0
bind " " windowlist -b
```

No matter what other `termcapinfo` lines I use, nothing fixes it.

As I said, connecting via `PuTTY` and running `screen` there it works as expected.  I have also found that if I do the same steps in just plain old `xterm` the issue does not occur.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... still no suggestions?  I can confirm that this issue is specific to xfce4-termnal, as I noted above, as it does not happen with xterm.  In further troubleshooting I tried the same steps on a Lubuntu 14.04 VM I created specifically to test this.  Using `lxterminal` the issue did not occur.  So, on my Xubuntu box I installed `lxterminal`, which did not drag in any other dependencies, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for this answer, I have scoured the net looking for the solution to "mousewheel scrolls history instead of output window" to no avail, but your pointer to switch from xfce-terminal to lxterminal solves it for me.